# How to make a for on Ionic 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

Hey guys i'm new with Ionic and I've got lot of doubts. In my project, I have requests and each request has an array of proposals. But when I pull the list from database I just wanna show the proposes who are 'Winner' and their requests are 'Finished', You guys got it? I'll show the code.

Html`

```
 <ion-segment-button value="third" (click)="getProposal('Winner')">
    Aceitas
  </ion-segment-button>
```

TypeScript

```
getProposals(status: string) {

if (status === 'Winner') {
  this.requestService.getProposalsPartner(this.user.email, status).then( resposta => {
        let proposalsWinner = resposta;
        for (let i in proposalsWinner) {
          if (proposalsWinner[i].request.status != 'Finished') {
            this.proposals = resposta;
          }              
        }
    })

} else {
      this.requestService.getProposalsPartner(this.user.email, status).then( resposta => {
      this.proposals = resposta;
    })  
}

}
```

So I've tried to make a for and only put on the list the proposals that follow the pattern I referred to. I've tested and it isnt working the way I wanted to. What's wrong on my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, it's worth to mention that you shouldn't use `for..in` with arrays.

**Why?** *Quoted* from [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript#10167931):

> The for...in syntax mentioned by others is for looping over an
>   object's properties; since an Array in JavaScript is just an object
>   with numeric property names (and an automatically-updated "length"
>   property), you can theoretically loop over an Array with it. But the
>   problem is that it doesn't restrict itself to the numeric property
>   values (remember that even methods are actually just properties whose
>   value is a closure), nor does it iterate over those in numeric order.
>   Therefore, the for...in syntax should not be used for looping through
>   Arrays.

See [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea) to see more answers related to.

---

That said, the main problem in your code is that you aren't really filtering the `resposta` *data*, you're just assigning `resposta` to `this.proposals`. To filter, you can use (of course) [**`Array#filter`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), like this:

```
this.proposals = response.filter(res => res.request.status !== 'Finished');
```

Final code:

```
getProposals(status: string) {
  this.requestService.getProposalsPartner(this.user.email, status).then(response => {
    if (status === 'Winner') {
      this.proposals = response.filter(res => res.request.status !== 'Finished');
    } else {
      this.proposals = response;
    }
  });
}
```

**Template:**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="proposals">
  <div *ngFor="let proposal of proposals">
    {{ proposal | json }}
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I understood and you could help me a lot with the explanation, but when I typed (res => res.request.status) a message popped up "parameter 'res' has an any type". I typed (res: any) but didnt work, what's wrong?

Comment: @YgorFraga Strange.. try: `(res: Object)`

Comment: It didn't work, that's weird. I also tried "this.proposals = response.filter(res: any => res.request.status !== 'Finished');"

Comment: @YgorFraga well it seems like more warning showed by tslint that anything. Where is the error is being shown? Also, what's the error exactly?

Comment: Is being shown on 'res', the firts one on 'res => res.request.status'.

The exactly error: Parameter 'rest' has an any type.
(parameter) res: any

Comment: @YgorFraga `response.filter((res: any)...` should work.

Comment: Right, I didn't put (), thanks for helping lad! Your tips were valuable.